# Group rows with that are less than 15 days apart and assign min/max date

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, sql-server-2012

If the protocol_opening_date of different protocols are within 15 days of each other, i need to show them as one protocol in another column named expected start date.

I don't know how to copy my table here as it looks but i'll try to explain as much as i can.

So let's say if one protocol has the start_date of 24.01.2018 and end_date of 30.01.2018 and an other one has start_date of 25.01.2018 and end_date of 10.02.2018

I need to display them as a different protocol with a start_date of 24.01 and end_date of 10.02 because they are 15 days within each other.

Another big issue is that i don't have a clue how to compare these two protocols with a third or fourth one. Because even if there is more than 2 protocols in the same date interval, i don't know how to compare them to each other.

[image]

Edit: I added a portion of the table, same colors are the protocols that's been combined into one protocol. Beklenen_baslangıc == expected_start_date

Comment: So it should be transitive? I.e. if we have one protocol every 14 days throughout a year, we should get one result the entire length of the year, combining all of these?

Comment: What RDBMs are you using (MySQL, SQL Server, etc) and what version. This could be solved easily with window functions.

Comment: Sql server 2012 @SalmanA

Comment: We create protocols based on patients, not based on date or a spesific amount of protocols per year. @Damien_The_Unbeliever

Comment: I was meaning more "if we find this pattern" rather than saying that's how it's been produced.

Comment: Any patient can have N number of protocols assigned. The thing is we need to shorten the amount of protocols created based on their creation and end dates which has a rule of being 15 days within eachother.I hope i clarified it enough.

Comment: How is 15 days within each other counted? StartDate of previous compared to StartDate of next or EndDate of prev to Start Date of next?

Comment: Its the difference between StartDate1 and StartDate2 @SalmanA

Comment: It's almost like a "Combination Set" . If two dates intersect in less than 15 days, we combine them.

Comment: See if you can provide additional data (more dates and a description of which dates needs to be combined together). It is doable in SQL 2012.

Comment: I added a portion of the table , i hope it makes sense to you. @SalmanA

Comment: It looks like 4810711 (end date  10/2 + 15 days = 25/2) overlaps 4862536 (start date 23/2). Can you confirm if that is the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, you could use the `LAG` function for this. The basic idea is to assign a 0/1 value to each row: if it is within 15 days of previous row then 0 else 1. Then use `SUM() OVER ()` to convert the 1s and 0s to numbers which could be used for grouping.

Note that this could group much longer date ranges together e.g. `01-01`, `01-11`, `01-21`, `02-01` and `02-11` will be grouped together although the first and last dates are more than 15 days apart.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE (HASTA_ID INT, PROTOKOL_ID INT, STARTDATE DATE, ENDDATE DATE);
INSERT INTO @T VALUES
(273065, 11, '2018-01-24', '2018-01-30'),
(273065, 12, '2018-01-25', '2018-02-10'),
(273065, 13, '2018-01-30', '2018-01-30'),
(273065, 14, '2018-02-23', '2018-02-28'),
(273065, 15, '2018-03-21', '2018-03-29'),
(273065, 16, '2018-05-03', '2018-05-04'),
(273065, 17, '2018-05-03', '2018-05-08'),
(273065, 18, '2018-05-14', '2018-05-22'),
(273065, 19, '2018-05-22', '2018-05-23'),
(273065, 20, '2018-09-20', '2018-09-30');

WITH CTE1 AS (
    SELECT *, CASE WHEN LAG(STARTDATE) OVER (PARTITION BY HASTA_ID ORDER BY STARTDATE) >= DATEADD(DAY, -14, STARTDATE) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS CHG
    FROM @T
), CTE2 AS (
    SELECT *, SUM(CHG) OVER (PARTITION BY HASTA_ID ORDER BY STARTDATE) AS GRP
    FROM CTE1
)
SELECT *,
    MIN(STARTDATE) OVER (PARTITION BY HASTA_ID, GRP) AS EX_STARTDATE,
    MAX(ENDDATE) OVER (PARTITION BY HASTA_ID, GRP) AS EX_ENDDATE
FROM CTE2
ORDER BY HASTA_ID, STARTDATE
```

[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f49a61fcef82a5cf9d99644d1a231091)